# How to add custom pipeline in azureDevops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

i have create CI/CD pipeline in azureDevops.
i need to add custom condition for when only previous task succeeded then it will execute.

so please help me 
what i have to write in Custom condition ?

I have attached below screen short where i need to add some custom condition.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i need to add custom condition for when only previous task succeeded then it will execute.

There is directly option **`Only when all previous tasks have succeeded`**, which is used to determine if **all** the previous tasks have succeeded.

If you want to give the condition that **just when only the one previous task succeeded**, there is no such out of box option to use. We could use the workaround that Napoleon answered:

> `write the result of the previous task to a variable and then check that variable in your condition`

**In addition**, I posted this answer to emphasize the choice of conditions, we need use **`always()`** not `succeeded()` or `failed()`. That because the syntax of condition is for all previous steps/jobs:

Check the document [Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for some more details.

For example:

I add three tasks in my pipeline:

1. Command line-Intentionally let it run failed
2. Run Inline Powershell-create a variable, assign it a value.

   ```
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TaskStatus;]Succeeded"
   ```
3. Command line-Custom Condition checking that variable.

   ```
    and(always(), eq(variables['TaskStatus'], 'Succeeded'))
   ```

[image]

[image]

If we use the condition `succeeded()` or `failed()`, whether its execution is still affected by all previous task execution results (First command line task.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi
Do I need to add  Powershell-create first?
and if need then how to add this.
Please let me know so I can achieve my custom pipeline.
Please guide me.

Comment: @MitulPatel, No, you do not  need to create that Powershell task first, that is used for testing. You can just create a powershell scripts eg. `test.ps1` in your project, then execute/run this scripts in the task, which before your custom build task.

Comment: I appreciate your help.
Thank you so much Leo.

Comment: but dear we are applying other approach to add come custom condition like: " 

in(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Failed', 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues') " 

so in this condition previous task will failed or succeed next will execute.

Comment: @MitulPatel, Yes, I know this approach, but it use the `Agent.JobStatus` not `Agent.TaskStatus`, So, I am not sure if it works for you. Since you want to add custom condition for when only **previous task** succeeded. But if it works for you, you can share it as answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the result of the previous task to a variable and then check that variable in your condition.

Answer (score 0):

i have found some custom condition which has fulfill my desire task.

in(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Failed', 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues')

in above custom condition for if the prev task will 'failed' or 'succeeded' next task will executed.